# How to convert a python datetime to a delphi TDateTime?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I need to convert `datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 16, 22, 9, 920000)`  into the Delphi TDateTime value `43191.68205925926`, on Python versions < 3.2.

I tried

```
def pdt2ddt(pydt):  # py datetime into delphi time
   start = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
   delta = pydt - start
   seconds = (delta - datetime.timedelta(days=delta.days)).total_seconds()
   return seconds / 3600 / 24
```

but `timedelta.total_seconds()` works only if the python version is 3.2 and above.

Delphi `TDateTime` values are expressed as a double floating point value counting days since midnight 1899-12-30.

Comment: The meaning of Delphi's datetime is the number of days since 30 Dec 1899, stored as a double value. (I get that from multiple Delphi docs.) So find that number of days in Python and store it in a float variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Delphi value is the number of days since a specific epoch, 1899-12-30. Construct a `timedelta` from the value as the `days` argument and add the epoch to go from Delphi to Python, and to go the other way, produce a delta between the Python datetime and the epoch, and divide the result by a `timedelta(days=1)` value (Python 3.2 / Python 2.7 and newer) or just add up the `seconds` and `microseconds` components and divide by the number of seconds in a day for older Python versions:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# A delphi datetime value is the (fractional) number of days since the epoch
# e.g. 42 minutes past the the UNIX epoch is 25569.029166666667 in Delphi terms.
DELPHI_EPOCH = datetime(1899, 12, 30)

def datetime_fromdelphi(dvalue):
    return DELPHI_EPOCH + timedelta(days=dvalue)

def datetime_todelphi(dt):
    try:
        return (dt - DELPHI_EPOCH) / timedelta(days=1)
    except TypeError:
        # Python 2.7 / Python 3.1 or older don't support division
        delta = dt - DELPHI_EPOCH
        return delta.days + (delta.seconds + delta.microseconds / 1000000.0) / 24 / 3600
```

This just uses an adjusted version of the [equivalency documented for `timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to get the exact number of days as a floating point number.

Demo:

```
>>> datetime_fromdelphi(43191.68205925926)
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 16, 22, 9, 920000)
>>> datetime_todelphi(datetime(2018, 4, 1, 16, 22, 9, 920000))
43191.682059259256
```

Answer (score 0):

Works also great with evalStr():

```
PyEngine_netA.ExecString(('from datetime import datetime, timedelta'));
PyEngine_netA.ExecString(UTF8Encode('DELPHI_EPOCH= datetime(1899,12,30)'));
PyEngine_netA.ExecString('def datetime_fromdelphi(dvalue):'+LF+
                         '  return DELPHI_EPOCH + timedelta(days=dvalue)');
println(PyEngine_netA.EvalStr(('datetime_fromdelphi(43191.68205925926)')));
```